# How do I pass parameter to ViewModel's constructor in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I see people suggests using Messenger/EventAggregator to pass parameter to ViewModel when "current" target is changed, but it doesn't work on my case.

Say I have a ViewModel class like this:

```
class CustomerViewModel
{
    CustomerViewModel(int customerId) {}
}
```

And:

1. I have views of same type in the application shell at the same time.
2. For each view, there is a unique CustomerViewModel instance for it. Each CustomerViewModel instance can have different customerId.
   (which is similar to Visual Studio IDE, multiple document opened at
   the same time)

I don't want to write code like "this.DataContext = new CustomerViewModel(id)" in my View class. What's the MVVM way to handle such case?

Thanks.

Comment: To answer ypur question `EventAggregator`is the way of doing it in `MVVM`. Why can't you use it? Any reasons?

Comment: @RV1987 I cannot use EventAggregator because I want to get the parameters when the ViewModel is created.

Comment: i think you have to use viewmodellocator that can create one object for viewmodel and we can use same object in whole application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this case, first - decide if you're using a [View first or View Model first](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/186609.aspx/1) approach.

Using the EventAggregator is a valid option.

Another option is to have your ViewModel implement an interface and then use some [IoC/DI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163739.aspx) such as [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) or Unity to get the instance of the ViewModel. Using this method, you can define an `Initalize(int Id)` function which you know the ViewModel must implement. 
You don't need your View to know the CustomerViewModel class, only the interface.

I should note that if you are using some kind of **DI**, you can always inject that parameter to the ViewModel. IIRC in Unity this can be done a bit easier then in MEF (you simply register the value and then create the ViewModel which depends on that type).

Comment: I think Initialize() method works for me. What's IIRC? Do you mean using ResolveOverrides?

Comment: IIRC is short for "If I Remember Correctly" (sorry for that:). And I checked this can be done rather easily in Unity, using `RegisterInstance` (or `RegisterType`) and `Resolve`ing the ViewModel that needs that type